# How to map derived class' columns in TPT, Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities - WorkItem and TestSuite - where WorkItem is the abstract class and TestSuite implements it. The question is that how to map TestSuite properties to database columns? In case of Workitem I can do it as you can see below. But in case of TestSuite, I cannot. ReSharper does not offer the Property method.

How to map columns of derived class? In the example below: How to map WORKITEM_TEST_SUITE.TEST_SUITE_TYPE_ID column to TestSuiteEntity class? It is possible? Shall I live with the fact EF is going to create column names for me?

What I did so far?

- I searched a lot, and every article deals only with the table mapping, and not the column mapping

It is important for me to have the control over column mapping.

WorkItem entity:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<WorkItemEntity> ( ).ToTable ( "WORKITEM" );
            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkItemEntity> ( ).HasKey ( k => k.Id );
            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkItemEntity> ( ).Property ( p => p.Id ).HasColumnName ( "ID" );
```

Workitem table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WORKITEM]
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    -- other columns
)
```

TestSuite entity:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TestSuiteEntity> ( ).ToTable ( "WORKITEM_TEST_SUITE" );
            modelBuilder.Entity<TestSuiteEntity>()//--> no property method!
```

Table where TestSuite stuff is stored.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WORKITEM_TEST_SUITE] (  [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [TEST_SUITE_TYPE_ID] INT NOT NULL, 
    -- other columns )
```

**Update**:

Despite the fact that I have restarted Visual Studio for a few times to exclude the possibility intellisense / resharper haven't load the available methods, properties correctly, a day later the property method appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that I have restarted Visual Studio for a few times to exclude the possibility intellisense / resharper haven't load the available methods, properties correctly, a day later the property method appears.